# Python recursion updates an array

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

Might I ask a question a bout Python recursion? I would like to check the logic behind this, and why this is able to keep updating the results?

The question:
A DFS recursion is constructed to append all its children nodes with a specified condition met, e.g., if a node’s end indicator is True, we are going to add this node to the array. This recursion will be used in another function.

2. My code:

```
    def dfs(self, level, ls):
        # if we meet the end of a level, this level’s information will be added to the returned list
        if level.end:
            ls.append(level.info)
        # go further to explore this level’s children, even an end is met. 
        for c in level.child:
            ls = self.dfs(level.child[c], ls)
        return ls
```

The `DFS` will be called by:

```
ls = self.dfs(self.curr, [])
```

The level is a self-defined Trie:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = collections.defaultdict(Trie)
        # self.child = {}
        self.end = False 
        self.w = ''
        self.f = 0
```

I am not sure why this `ls` will get updated in each for loop iteration, and then pass to the next iteration. I am also surprised that, the following codes are also working:

```
        for c in level.child:
            self.dfs(level.child[c], ls)
```

Without returning the `ls`. I am not sure why this works?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best,

Naive Python learner

Comment: Is `level.child[c]` a dictionary? Please include the class that definition. I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but note that `ls` is being modified in place, so `ls = self.dfs(level.child[c], ls)` is just reassigning `ls` to itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am going to include the class here. Thanks.

Comment: @joseville The question here is that ```ls = self.dfs``` will get itself updating. But why ```self.dfs``` without assigning will also update the ```ls```? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the list is passed into `dfs`, it is not the current values in the `list` that are passed, but instead a reference (a pointer) to the `list` in memory. There is only one `list`. This is called pass by reference.

Similarly, when the code assigns the output of `dfs` to `ls`, this is literally replacing the pointer to the `list` object with a pointer to the `list` object, i.e. it is doing nothing.

There is even an answer related to this in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). There’s some further reading with examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference#986145).

If you want to make your code behave the way you’re thinking it does, you can construct a new `list` instead of editing the single `list`. There are some reasons to do this, but with a normal `list` it is fairly expensive and provides little value. To see it in action, change the `append` call to:

```py
    ls = ls + [level.info]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I think this is what I am looking for. Can we say ```list``` here behaves more likely a global variable, and will get update in each iteration? ```list += [level.info]``` is going to create a new memory space, and assign the value with ```list + [level.info]```. But, ```list.append()``` will only update the value, but not the reference.

Comment: Remember that arguments are passed by assignment in Python. (Does it mean the function only takes out the values from the argument? ) Since assignment just creates references to objects, there’s no alias between an argument name in the caller and callee, (The argument in the caller and callee are totally unrelated, like you said the returned ```ls``` is a new object. ) and so no call-by-reference per se.

Comment: The second StackOverflow answer saves me. The original Python document is not that clear. Awesome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Call by assignment is explained by Ned Bachelder here very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns. Also, remember to upvote and accept answers that helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.